# BeautifulSoup to Data Frame With Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup

New to programming here, so forgive the silly questions.  I've been trying to work out how to Python for web scraping and a lot of the YouTube videos and other questions *kinda* get me there, I'm having a hard time relating the answer to my actual code.

My code so far is:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import csv
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/English/Racing/LocalResults.aspx?RaceDate=2021/02/06&Racecourse=ST&RaceNo=1"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

html = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")

soup_level1=soup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')


race_soup = soup_level1.find("tbody", class_="f_fs13")
print(race_soup.text.strip())

results_soup = soup_level1.find("tbody", class_="f_fs12")
print(results_soup.text.strip())


datalist = [] #empty list
x = 0 #counter
print('good')


driver.close()
```

This will generate the parsed data, but now I am stuck as how to move it from text to a data frame with pandas.  I'm sure it is simple, but all of the instructional material I've seen isn't clicking for me.

Also, The code so far is just sort of copy and pasted chunks from different websites that I got to work with trial and error.  I'm not sure if any of it is redundant, so if there is a neater way to go about it, I would appreciate that feedback as well!

Thanks in advance,
Spencer

Comment: `dfs = pd.read_html(driver.page_source)` this will return a list of all the `<table>` tags it finds as dataframes. Just a matter of pulling out the table you want (provided there are `<table>` tags found)

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  I knew it had to be something simple, but I couldn't quite piece it together.

Another question is, how do I choose which table(s) I want and exclude the others?  For example, there are more than two tables on the page, but I just want the first two.  How can I stop after that?

Comment: so is that `'race'`, and `'result'`?

Comment: Yeah.  The 'race' table just has information about the race itself (date, track, time, etc).  The 'results" table has the actual times the horses ran, place finished, etc.  Then there are other tables about betting pay offs and other things that I do not care about and do not want pandas to work with.

Comment: ya ok. little trickier since it's the `<tbody>` tags that have the specific class attribute. Give me a sec, I'll post the solution

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it.  It's not the end of the world, as I can just, you know, ignore those tables lol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import csv
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/English/Racing/LocalResults.aspx?RaceDate=2021/02/06&Racecourse=ST&RaceNo=1"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

html = driver.execute_script("return document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "f_fs13")))
htmlStr = driver.page_source

soup_level1 = soup(htmlStr, 'html.parser')

race_soup = soup_level1.find('tbody',{'class':'f_fs13'}).find_parent('table')
results_soup = soup_level1.find('tbody',{'class':'f_fs12'}).find_parent('table')

df1 = pd.read_html(str(race_soup))[0]
print(df1)

df2 = pd.read_html(str(results_soup))[0]
print(df2)



datalist = [] #empty list
x = 0 #counter
print('good')


driver.close()
```

Comment: Ran into this error:

AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_parent'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Spenc\Desktop\Python Stuff\selenium test.py", line 21, in <module>
    race_soup = soup_level1('tbody',{'class':'f_fs13'}).find_parent('table')
  File "C:\Users\Spenc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py", line 2173, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(
AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_parent'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Spenc\Desktop\Python Stuff\selenium test.py", line 21, in <module>
    race_soup = soup_level1.find('tbody',{'class':'f_fs13'}).find_parent('table')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_parent'

Do you mind if I ask you to explain what you're doing to try and fix this?  It looks like the new code is saying "go to this element, and then find the parent, and then give me just that table".  Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: hmmm. ok. let me debug on my end. what version of beautifulsoup you running?

Comment: I think bs4?  Whatever the most recent one is, I guess.

Comment: do `import bs4`
`print(bs4.__version__)` I'm on 4.6.0

Comment: it tells me version 4.9.3

Comment: ok. I think i found the issue. It was trying to parse the data/html before the page was rendered. So put an wait element in there. try now.